# Get value from object based on string concatenation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a small website written with React & Typescript which works with a Spring boot backend. I'm now trying to implement multiple languages on it but I am hitting an issue.

Before the implementation of languages the issue wasn't present because I could just get the value based on it's name:

```
<div className="product-category-list">
  {props.productCategory.map(function (item, id) {
    return <div className="product-category-div">
      <img className="product-category-image" src={"data:image/png;base64, " + item.picture}/>
      <p className="product-category-title">{ item.name }</p>
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

This results in the value of `item.name` being shown on the website the way it should be.

Now the code is different because the name property of item has been changed to multiple values (nameEN, nameFR, nameNL, ...). To implement this the language is saved on the application and can get called. So now the code is as follows:

```
<div className="product-category-list">
  {props.productCategory.map(function (item, id) {
    return <div className="product-category-div">
      <img className="product-category-image" src={"data:image/png;base64, " + item.picture}/>
      <p className="product-category-title">{ "item.name".concat(getLanguage().toUpperCase()) }</p>
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

Because of this change the website shows the String `item.nameEN` or `item.nameNL` in the frontend instead of the value. I've tried several ways of fixing it and researched it but I can't find any information on this specific issue.

I'm looking for a way to be able to get the value of an item key which is build based on a String concatenation. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm very stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you locked into using a separate item key for each language?  Why not have the name element itself be a dictionary where key = language and value = desired string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your previous code which you said was working:

`<p className="product-category-title">{ item.name }</p>`

Here you are accessing a property `name` of the object `item`.

In your new code:

`<p className="product-category-title">{ "item.name".concat(getLanguage().toUpperCase()) }</p>`

Here you are just returning a string with the value `"item.nameEN"` and not accessing the object called `item`.

What you want is to still access `item` but do that with a key that you are building dynamically. Try this:

`<p className="product-category-title">{ item["name" + getLanguage().toUpperCase()] }</p>`

Comment: This fixed the issue indeed, didn't know it worked liked that.
Because of typescript I had to implement some interface intersection but now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just replacing

```
"item.name".concat(getLanguage().toUpperCase())
```

with

```
item["name" + getLanguage().toUpperCase()
```

should work fine